# Erro ao usar many to many laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um grupo de Usuarios que tem relacionamento Many To Many, para criar esse relacionamento fiz uma função beLongsToMany dentro do model Usuarios. Porém toda vez que chamo essa função eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method  Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Pessoas()'

```
public function Pessoas(){
return $this->belongsToMany('entidades\Pessoas', 'pessoa_id');
}
```

Chamada:

```
Usuarios::where('usuario_id', $usuario_id)->Pessoas()->toSql();
```

Para cada um dos meus usuários eu quero pegar o registros das pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer carregar os usuários e também as informações das pessoas, se for isso, use:

```
Usuarios::where('usuario_id', $usuario_id)->with('Pessoas')->toSql();
```

Para você usar a função `Pessoas` você precisa chamar ele de uma instância do `Usuarios`, se você chama primeiro a função `where` você não conseguirá chamar a função `Pessoas` porque o `where` retorna uma instância do `Builder`.

Referencias:

- [Eager Loadind (with)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Interessante, vou tentar usar essa abordagem também. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para definir o relacionamento *Many To Many* é necessário ter 3 tabelas, no seu caso seria: **usuarios**, **pessoas** e **pessoa_usuario**. A 3 tabela deve seguir o  padrão de ordem alfabética.

No *Model* de Usuarios você deve colocar o seguinte:

```
public function pessoas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( Pessoas::class, 'pessoa_usuario' ); // Primeiro parâmetro é o Model que você vai se relacionar e o segundo é o nome da tabela.
}
```

A função *belongsToMany* recebe 4 parâmetros estamos usando apenas 2 porque estou supondo que sua estrutura segue o padrão orientado pelo *Laravel.* Para mais informações é só conferir a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

E para listar todos os usuários que possuam o relacionamento basta você usar o seguinte:

```
Usuarios::where('usuario_id', $usuario_id)->with('Pessoas')->get();
```

Comment: Entendi vou tentar aqui e já retorno com uma posição. Obrigado!!!